# Parse installations doesn't match up to play store statistics

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse as back end for my Android app. I used Parse installations feature, which should save Android device information of an installation, so it should be equivalent to Play store statistics. But Parse Installations are almost 4 times to Play store count. What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Somewhat popular paid app? Could be people that got it on the black market. Otherwise, everybody measures differently.

Comment: @zapl No, it's a new app. I have about 25 installs in play store. But in Parse it shows around 90. BTW here is the [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vlabs.lollygag)